# 403 Forbidden - Tranmission on Apple Tv

Tags: appletv, transmission

I am having a problem using Transmission on my Apple Tv .. I'm still getting a 403 Forbidden error when trying to view the web client, however when I go to my settings.json under "Users/Frontrow/Library/Application Support/transmission-daemon/" it is listed like this:

"rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1,192.168.1.*", 
 "rpc-whitelist-enabled": false,

So how is it I'm still getting 403 error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the frontrow user is actually running transmission-daemon, if it's running as root it doesn't use that configuration file. Also, transmission-daemon needs to restart to pick up changes to the config file.